# set font-size for appended text only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

Currently a link have the description like this:

```
<a href="#">description</a>
```

Now, I would append text after the description:

```
$('a').append('&gt;')
```

How can I use the font-size for appended text only?

```
description>
//        ^^^ setting font-size for this only
// this won't work
 $('a').append('&gt;').css('font-size','20px')
```

I wouldn't like to wrap appended text with span for some reason.

I don't know much more about regex but hope this can be done with regex.

Comment: if you don't want to wrap, you can't achieve it

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `:after` pseudo-element, but the extra content will be part of the link text instead of appearing right after the closing `a` tag.

If you turn off the text-decoration, you may be make do with this design pattern.

You can then use your jQuery to add or toggle the class "marked" to the appropriate
links.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
a.marked:after {
  /* content: '>'; this also works... */
  content: '\3e'; /* '3e' is the hex code for the > symbol */
  font-size: 2.0em;
  margin-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">description</a>
<br><br>
<a class="marked" href="#">description</a>
```

Reference: Hex codes for entities can be found at:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3e/index.htm

Comment: Not quite, you still need jQuery to toggle the class name, but upvote appreciated!

Comment: Well the OP sounds like he doesn't require adding classes and etc, but simply adding a `>` after the link. CSS should do it :)

Comment: Appending text to element content and using CSS `:after` are two different things and have different effects in many circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like,

```
$('a').append('<font size="10">&gt;</font>');
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n8aynb42/)**

**Note:** You can't do without an extra element

Comment: If the OP wants the `>` symbol outside of the `a`, this is the way to go.  The `font` tag is deprecated, but a `span` would work as well with an inline style or a class.

Comment: `<font size="10">` has undefined meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the added character in an element so that you can set styles on it. This can be done in several ways, e.g.

```js
$('a').append('<span style="font-size: 20px">></span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">description</a>
```